# Check a particular dependency in provided scope of tomee

Tags: maven, tomcat, hazelcast, apache-tomee

I have a project which uses hazelcast and it suddenly started having consistency issues. It worked fine for 2 years in production and all of a sudden many users started reporting consistency issue in its distributed map. The hazelcast dependency has `provided` scope in my dependency tree. We earlier tested in hazelcast version 3.5.2 where it used to work perfectly.

I wanted to check the version provided by my tomee container. WIs there a way to do so?

Comment: We have a 2 node distributed cluster where we use hazelcast's distributed map. The data in both nodes was different given which should't be since we had backupCount=1 and used tcp-ip discovery.

Comment: Unless I am missing something from your explanation, the data is indeed expected to be different when using IMap. Data would be same only if using ReplicatedMap. So details on what type of Map is used, how you determine data is different or same and what is really expected from Hazelcast on consistency, would be helpful.

Comment: I am using com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl. I got this using Reflection. FYI, I am new to Hazelcast.

Comment: If there was no specific reason then you should be using standard APIs to access Hazelcast Map: IMap map = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance().getMap("my-map");